# Home shortcut key to my designated webpage?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I was wondering if there is an android shortcut to make things more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

That one is quite easy:

1. Make a bookmark to the desired target in your web browser
2. Create a shortcut to that bookmark on your desktop

The second step is sometimes offered by the browser itself, but always possible using the bookmark widget shipping with Android itself.